# Using .ThenBy in a Linq causes inner object to be null

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am ingesting a response from the Bureau of Labor Statistics. I can grab a maximum of 20 years of data at a time. The response returns the last year and last month first and then descends from there.

I am trying to sort by year and month ascending.

Where year = a 4 digit year.
Period = the letter M followed by a digit designating the month, for example January = M01.

Example Sorting

- 1948 M01
- 1948 M02
- 1948 M03
- .... Etc

below are the object(s).

```
  public class BLSResponse
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int responseTime { get; set; }
        public List<string> message { get; set; }
        public Results Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public List<Series> series { get; set; }
    }

    public class Series
    {
        public string seriesID { get; set; }
        public Catalog catalog { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Catalog
    {
        public string series_title { get; set; }
        public string series_id { get; set; }
        public string seasonality { get; set; }
        public string survey_name { get; set; }
        public string survey_abbreviation { get; set; }
        public string measure_data_type { get; set; }
        public string commerce_industry { get; set; }
        public string occupation { get; set; }
        public string cps_labor_force_status { get; set; }
        public string demographic_age { get; set; }
        public string demographic_ethnic_origin { get; set; }
        public string demographic_race { get; set; }
        public string demographic_gender { get; set; }
        public string demographic_education { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string period { get; set; }
        public string periodName { get; set; }
        public string latest { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public List<Footnote> footnotes { get; set; }
        public Calculations calculations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Calculations
    {
        public Net_Changes net_changes { get; set; }
        public Pct_Changes pct_changes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Net_Changes
    {
        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public string _1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("3")]
        public string _3 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("6")]
        public string _6 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("12")]
        public string _12 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pct_Changes
    {
        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public string _1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("3")]
        public string _3 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("6")]
        public string _6 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("12")]
        public string _12 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Footnote
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

The below sort, sorts them by year just fine.

```
blsResponse.Results.series.ForEach(x => x.data = x.data.OrderBy(x => x.year).ToList());
```

however if I try any of the below, then all of the sudden the calculations object that is apart of
the data is now null.

**1**

```
blsResponse.Results.series.ForEach(x => x.data = (x.data.OrderBy(y => y.year).ThenBy(p => p.period)).ToList());
```

**2**

```
blsResponse.Results.series.ForEach(x => x.data = x.data.OrderBy(x => x.year + x.period).ToList());
```

**Here is an example JSON response for 1948 - 1949**

```
{
    "status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
    "responseTime": 171,
    "message": [],
    "Results": {
        "series": [
            {
                "seriesID": "LNS11000000",
                "catalog": {
                    "series_title": "(Seas) Civilian Labor Force Level",
                    "series_id": "LNS11000000",
                    "seasonality": "Seasonally Adjusted",
                    "survey_name": "Labor Force Statistics from the Current Population Survey",
                    "survey_abbreviation": "LN",
                    "measure_data_type": "Number in thousands",
                    "commerce_industry": "All Industries",
                    "occupation": "All Occupations",
                    "cps_labor_force_status": "Civilian labor force",
                    "demographic_age": "16 years and over",
                    "demographic_ethnic_origin": "All Origins",
                    "demographic_race": "All Races",
                    "demographic_gender": "Both Sexes",
                    "demographic_education": "All educational levels"
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "61908",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-97",
                                "3": "275",
                                "6": "960",
                                "12": "739"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.2",
                                "3": "0.4",
                                "6": "1.6",
                                "12": "1.2"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "62005",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-180",
                                "3": "415",
                                "6": "746",
                                "12": "1303"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.3",
                                "3": "0.7",
                                "6": "1.2",
                                "12": "2.1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "62185",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "552",
                                "3": "884",
                                "6": "1178",
                                "12": "1539"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.9",
                                "3": "1.4",
                                "6": "1.9",
                                "12": "2.5"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "61633",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "43",
                                "3": "685",
                                "6": "560",
                                "12": "818"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.1",
                                "3": "1.1",
                                "6": "0.9",
                                "12": "1.3"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "61590",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "289",
                                "3": "331",
                                "6": "533",
                                "12": "784"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.5",
                                "3": "0.5",
                                "6": "0.9",
                                "12": "1.3"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "61301",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "353",
                                "3": "294",
                                "6": "530",
                                "12": "120"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.6",
                                "3": "0.5",
                                "6": "0.9",
                                "12": "0.2"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "60948",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-311",
                                "3": "-125",
                                "6": "-221",
                                "12": "-9"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.5",
                                "3": "-0.2",
                                "6": "-0.4",
                                "12": "0.0"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "61259",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "252",
                                "3": "202",
                                "6": "557",
                                "12": "1287"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.4",
                                "3": "0.3",
                                "6": "0.9",
                                "12": "2.1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "61007",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-66",
                                "3": "236",
                                "6": "361",
                                "12": "330"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.1",
                                "3": "0.4",
                                "6": "0.6",
                                "12": "0.5"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "61073",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "16",
                                "3": "-96",
                                "6": "258",
                                "12": "1003"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.0",
                                "3": "-0.2",
                                "6": "0.4",
                                "12": "1.7"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "61057",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "286",
                                "3": "355",
                                "6": "251",
                                "12": "533"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.5",
                                "3": "0.6",
                                "6": "0.4",
                                "12": "0.9"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1949",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "60771",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-398",
                                "3": "125",
                                "6": "-410",
                                "12": "676"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.7",
                                "3": "0.2",
                                "6": "-0.7",
                                "12": "1.1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "61169",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "467",
                                "3": "354",
                                "6": "212"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.8",
                                "3": "0.6",
                                "6": "0.3"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "60702",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "56",
                                "3": "-104",
                                "6": "730"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.1",
                                "3": "-0.2",
                                "6": "1.2"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "60646",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-169",
                                "3": "-535",
                                "6": "-31"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.3",
                                "3": "-0.9",
                                "6": "-0.1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "60815",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "9",
                                "3": "-142",
                                "6": "745"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.0",
                                "3": "-0.2",
                                "6": "1.2"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "60806",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-375",
                                "3": "834",
                                "6": "282"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.6",
                                "3": "1.4",
                                "6": "0.5"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "61181",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "224",
                                "3": "504",
                                "6": "1086"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.4",
                                "3": "0.8",
                                "6": "1.8"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "60957",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "985",
                                "3": "887"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "1.6",
                                "3": "1.5"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "59972",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-705",
                                "3": "-552"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-1.2",
                                "3": "-0.9"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "60677",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "607",
                                "3": "582"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "1.0",
                                "3": "1.0"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "60070",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "-454"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "-0.8"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "60524",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "calculations": {
                            "net_changes": {
                                "1": "429"
                            },
                            "pct_changes": {
                                "1": "0.7"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1948",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "60095",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I also tried sorting  by period and then grouping by year and none of that worked either.

What am I missing here? I feel like if I can OrderBy I should be able to OrderBy.ThenBy, correct?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Please share a [mre] including sample data setup.

Comment: Added Json response for years 1948 - 1949. I can't really share my API call as that would expose an API Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided data does not contain for `calculations` property in JSON for year `1948` and `M01` period and after sorting this record becomes first (was last in the original data). The reordering does not affect the `Datum` instances itself.

Comment: OH MY, you are right. I am going to mark your as the answer. thank you.

Comment: it won't let me delete as you have answered it already. Either way, oh my I spent like 45 minutes totally flabbergasted by this.

Comment: @AdamSchneider sometimes it happens even to all of us, I would say. I'm afraid to count the hours wasted on debugging when missing something like this =) Again - was glad to help!